# simple Android Project error

Tags: android, project

At first, my Android project well ok. 
I was away from my Android Project for a month.
Now, whenever simple Android projects are error, eventhough Hello World prj with Android.
There is no error in my simple but at he name of project Folder , there is red cross for error sign.
I was updated Installed Android parckage.
However, it is not ok.
Is there anyone who know how is it?

Comment: clean your project, if you are using eclipse, on the window go to PROJECT and there click clean.

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE are you using. IF Eclipse go to project in the task bar and clean your project.
Also check problems window.

Answer (score 0):

if above solution can't help you . create a new project and copy src , res and manifest into it .

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem explore
Error generating final archive:Debug certificate expired on 8/5/11 2:35 PM!
So, delete debug.keystore file at window machine %USERHOME%/debug.keystore
clean the project.
All are fine!

Answer (score 0):

There are might be two solutions
Clean project
Simply copy past your code into new android project

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild should resolve the problem.

Comment: Please add more details.